# Elessar - get the values from bar which are fixed and selected and insert values to the db

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, elessar

I'm using Elessar Library ( https://github.com/quarterto/Elessar ) to create blocks.

[image]

I'm trying to select blocks which are blue and subtract yellow ones, for example my code should insert value to database which is 3 hour (bw 10am-12am= 2 hour and 13:00-14:00= 1 hour total= 3 hours).
Could you please help me for my code?

```
$(function () {
    $('body').prepend(RangeBar({
       min: moment().startOf('day').format('LLLL'),
       max: moment().startOf('day').add(1, 'day').format('LLLL'),
       valueFormat: function(ts) {
          return moment(ts).format('HH:mm');
       },
       valueParse: function(date) {
          return moment(date).valueOf();
       },
       values: [
       [
          moment().startOf('day').add(5.0, 'hours').format('LLLL'),
          moment().startOf('day').add(6.0, 'hours').format('LLLL')
       ],
       [
          moment().startOf('day').add(12.0, 'hours').format('LLLL'),
          moment().startOf('day').add(13.0, 'hours').format('LLLL')
       ],
       [
          moment().endOf('day').subtract(5.0, 'hours').format('LLLL'),
          moment().endOf('day').subtract(4.0, 'hours').format('LLLL')
       ],
       ],
       label: function(a){
          var jsonText = JSON.stringify(a);
          return jsonText;
       },
       snap: 1000 * 60 * 30, 
       minSize: 1000 * 60 * 60, 
       bgLabels: 24,
       allowDelete: true,
       indicator: null
       }).on('changing', function(ev, ranges, changed) {
       $('pre.changing').html(JSON.stringify(ranges,null,2));
       }).$el);
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.elessar-range').addClass('fixed'); 
          // it helps to set read only values - yellow blocks.
       });

       $("#submit").click(function () {
              ...
       });
});
```

When I click the button, I want to insert values to db.
In other words, how can I parse the values which are blue?
Thanks in advance.